# Commitlog archive will always lost the lastest commitlog?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

everybody

I'm running cassandra2.2.8, and have configured commitlog archive to run automatically.

The commitlog_archiving.properties:

```
archive_command=/bin/cp %path /data1/backup/%name
```

But I noticed it always copy the files that have rotated, while not the commitlog that is working currently . for instance, I have a commitlog file CommitLog-5-1533697321883.log is working now, and after it's rotated to another file, CommitLog-5-1533697321884.log, the file CommitLog-5-1533697321883.log will get archived, now all sessions is going to the CommitLog-5-1533697321884.log file, but it's not backuped at all, will lost in a disaster recovery.

My question is, is this the designed behaviour? What can I do to improve this situation? or is there any improvement in the cassandra 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is designed behaviour - the current commit log is incomplete by design - that's why you get access to archived commit logs. (afaik, this is the same for most databases).

If your data is critical, you may need to consider tuning of consistency levels.

Comment: Also a question, Can the current commit log used to recover the data? I want to backup the current commit log every minute, Since I noticed the commit log get rotated after 20 minutes sometimes, that means I will loss 20 minutes' transactions in a disaster.

Comment: I'm not sure that it will be complete file if you do it on the opened file... commit log is rotated based on the fact that memtable is flushed, so you may tune that instead. But in your case, I would suggest to tune write consistency levels instead, and repair data from other nodes